# How to remove linkage of Entitltement Process with Case from backend or programatically?

Tags: casemilestone, entitlements

How we can **remove the linkage of Entitlement Process with Case** when we're using all the custom layouts with Visualforce pages?

For ex:

> SELECT Id, CaseNumber, EntitlementId,Entitlement.Name FROM Case where CaseNumber ='00075837'

I am unable to to removed Id and make it null ?I need to link another entitlement process with this case or I may not wants to do that. How we can do that ?

[image]

Updated Screen shot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image below (from the [SOAP Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_support.htm), it appears to me that Entitlement is also dependent on the Contact. It appears to me that you can't change the EntitlementId for a Case unless it's one that applies to the Contact for the Case. It's not shown on this diagram, but the Entitlement could also be related to the Asset and ProductIds as part of the Service Contract.

You don't want to change the EntitlementId unless you know *why* you're changing it and what it relates to.

[image: Case - Entitlement Schema]

**EDIT:**

Based on your comments and edits, I recommend you go through the following section in the Salesforce Help: [Set Up and Manage Entitlements and Milestones](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_parent_admin.htm&type=5). In order to change entitlements, you'll need to create a permission set that enables "Edit” permissions on entitlements and assign it to yourself and any other users who need that permission (see [Give Users Access to Entitlement Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_giving_users_access.htm&type=5)).

I think you'll also find the documentation helpful where it explains Entitlements and their relationships with other objects; particularly how to customize them with Cases through creating filtered lookups on both Entitlements and Assets.

Comment: Per business, our forms are rendering when we select category and sub-category, once case is created then want facility to change sub-category so that new form will come and based on new combination I need to link new entitlement process, How can I remove previous one and attached new? Need to identify impact on existing milestones also

Comment: I strongly suspect that you have multiple relationships involved here (lookups to other objects) that need to be resolved and edited at the same time. You can't just change the lookup to Entitlement without also changing the lookups to the other objects that are also affected. You'll need to sort that out in your schema what those are. You may also have validation rules that are preventing these things from happening.

Comment: You're right. Case has 2 child objects. From Child object has lookup to Case. Also Case has lookup to Account, So in order to do so on Entitlement, how can I do that ? Any suggestions . I dont have VR in place.

Comment: removed contact still entitlement is linked to the case.  Please screen shot attached.

Comment: @user4798115 See my edited answer.